# Ef is creating new table when I added ForeignKey to another DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have two `DbContext` in my project, `AppDbContext` and `MyNewApplicationDbContext`.

I am using `AppDbContext`  in multiple project that has table `Keyword`

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("Common");
    }
}
public class Keyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Keyword Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my new application I need to create table `PoemKeyword` in `MyNewApplicationDbContext`  like below with a foreign key to `Keyword` table(that is in AppDbContext)

```
public class MyNewApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("MyNewApplicationDbSchema");
        builder.Entity<PoemKeyword>()
                .HasKey(e => new { e.KeywordId, e.PoemId, e.PoetId });
        }
    public DbSet<PoemKeyword> PoemKeywords { get; set; }
}
public class PoemKeyword
{
    public int PoemId { get; set; }
    public int PoetId { get; set; }
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PoemId")]
    public virtual Poem Poem { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("KeywordId")]
    public virtual Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PoetId")]
    public virtual Poet Poet { get; set; }
}
```

then I added migrations but in new migrations It want to create new `Keyword` table but this table has already been added by `AppDbContext`

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Keyword",
                schema: "MyNewApplicationDbSchema",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ParentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Keyword", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Keyword_Keyword_ParentId",
                        column: x => x.ParentId,
                        principalSchema: "MyNewApplicationDbSchema",
                        principalTable: "Keyword",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

**Note:** `MyNewApplicationDbContext`  And `AppDbContext` they are two in one database

I have now `Common.Keyword` table in my database why EF wants to create `MyNewApplicationDbSchema.Keyword` table too?

**Edit**

I recently changed the schema name of two diffrent `DbContext` but the problem not solved yet

```
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("SameSchemaNameInAllDbContext");
```

Comment: 1 database + multiple DbContexts + migrations == problems. When generationg migrations, EF Core has no idea what is the target database state. Migrations are generated based on differences between current model and last model snapshot - both stored in the migrations project.

Comment: @IvanStoev both DbContext are in one migration project

Comment: @IvanStoev I deleted `public virtual Keyword Keyword { get; set; }` from `PoemKeyword` Entity Now EF don't add Keyword table .So Do you know what is problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class PoemKeyword
{
    public int PoemId { get; set; }
    public int PoetId { get; set; }
    public int KeywordId { get; set; }

    public virtual Poem Poem { get; set; }
    public virtual Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
    public virtual Poet Poet { get; set; }
    
}
```

Can u try to define like this. ET will recognize theese foreign key automaticly.
But dont forget the variables names should be same.
I mean if you define Poem as a Poem
 then u should define PoemId as a foreign key. 
My english is not great i hope this would help u

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's not about English, it just doesn't address the problem in hand.